# Given surface area of a cuboid, find it's integer side lengths.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Its a rather small problem once you've boiled it down to:

$2(ab + bc + ca) = 100$ (the surface area of said cuboid)

Now, I'm left with the equation:

$ab + bc + ca = 50$,

$3$ variables and $1$ equation. Is there any way to factor or apply a niche formula or similar to solve for lengths: $a, b, c$. Yes, the number is small so you could probably guess and check ( like $1, 2, 16$ works), but is there a proper way to deal with this kind of problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a\geq b\geq c$.

Thus, $$50\geq3c^2,$$ which gives $$1\leq c\leq 4$$ and we got not so many cases.

For example, for $c=1$ we obtain:
$$a+b+ab=50$$ or
$$(1+a)(1+b)=51,$$ which gives
$$1+a=17$$ and $$1+b=3.$$
The rest is similar.

Comment: Thank you so much, not really used to solving questions with more variables with equations, but may I ask why you did the 'let a >b>c... thing'.

Comment: Because the expression $ab+ac+bc$ is symmetric. In the answer we need to write all permutations of $\{a,b,c\}.$

Comment: Ah, makes sense, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: I missed the day on which you got the 100k reputation. Congratulations !

Comment: Thank you, @Claude!

Answer (score 0):

There is a small finite set of positive solutions. If you allow negative numbers, you get infinitely many solutions, such as
$$ (a,b,c) \mapsto (6a+2b+c, 3a+2b, -2a-b)  $$